Can you iterate an operation over every row of a dataframe using apply?
I frequently find myself using a for loop to perform row-wise operations involving multiple dataframes, along the lines of the following example:
# Sample data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, size = 20), b = sample(letters, size = 20))
df2 <- data.frame(c = sample(1:100, size = 20), d = sample(letters, size = 20))

# Sample loop operation
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  number.2 <- df2$c[i]
  letter.1 <- df1$b[df1$a == number.2]
  
  df2$x[i] <- ifelse(!is_empty(letter.1), paste0(letter.1), paste0("No match"))
}

The code does what I want, I just suspect that there's a more elegant way to go about it using apply.
Is there a way to do this using the apply family of functions?

What you've got here is a long way to code a common operation. This is a one-liner using match(), or you can make it more general to a greater variety of cases and columns using merge or one of dplyr's join functions.
match works well when you are matching one value. merge or join will work well if you are matching multiple columns. If you have a more complicated condition, like >= instead of ==, then you need a "non-equi join", which is supported in dplyr or data.table.
df2$result = df1[match(df2$c, df1$a), "b"]
df2
#     c d        x result
# 1  89 v No match   <NA>
# 2  34 z No match   <NA>
# 3  93 g No match   <NA>
# 4  69 p        p      p
# 5  72 q        x      x
# 6  76 r No match   <NA>
# 7  63 y No match   <NA>
# 8  13 b No match   <NA>
# 9  82 d No match   <NA>
# 10 91 m No match   <NA>
# 11 25 e        w      w
# 12 38 f No match   <NA>
# 13 21 c No match   <NA>
# 14 79 i        q      q
# 15 41 u No match   <NA>
# 16 47 o No match   <NA>
# 17 60 t No match   <NA>
# 18 16 j No match   <NA>
# 19  6 x No match   <NA>
# 20 96 n No match   <NA>


Use left_join: Note-- compare your x column and the b column
left_join(df2, df1, join_by(c == a)) %>%
    mutate(b = replace_na(b, 'No match'))

   c d        x        b
1  89 v No match No match
2  34 z No match No match
3  93 g No match No match
4  69 p        p        p
5  72 q        x        x
6  76 r No match No match
7  63 y No match No match
8  13 b No match No match
9  82 d No match No match
10 91 m No match No match
11 25 e        w        w
12 38 f No match No match
13 21 c No match No match
14 79 i        q        q
15 41 u No match No match
16 47 o No match No match
17 60 t No match No match
18 16 j No match No match
19  6 x No match No match
20 96 n No match No match


Another base R option, with merge
transform(
    merge(df2, df1, by.x = "c", by.y = "a", all.x = TRUE),
    x = ifelse(is.na(b), "No Match", b)
)[-3]

which gives
    c d        x
1   6 x No Match
2  13 b No Match
3  16 j No Match
4  21 c No Match
5  25 e        w
6  34 z No Match
7  38 f No Match
8  41 u No Match
9  47 o No Match
10 60 t No Match
11 63 y No Match
12 69 p        p
13 72 q        x
14 76 r No Match
15 79 i        q
16 82 d No Match
17 89 v No Match
18 91 m No Match
19 93 g No Match
20 96 n No Match

